# prepOverlay issue in Plone forms

Tags: jquery, plone

I'm trying to use prepOverlay for a form. It mostly works, except that the results display in the overlay instead of redirecting the whole page. I tried the example here http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.jquerytools/1.1b5 with the contact form and get the same results. It looks like it's at least possible to get the behavior I want since that is what the new user registration is doing - is there some magic code for the form I need to create?

Answer (score 1):

Check the **formselector** and the **closeselector** in your prepOverlay invocation. They must have the right css selector for the form the overlay loads.